# Add new object to incoming json string

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to parse an incoming json string and push a new
object to that.

I've tried it like this:

```
addSetting(category) {
    console.log(category.value); //Console.log = [{"meta":"","value":""}]
    category.value = JSON.parse(category.value).push({meta: "", value: ""});
    console.log(category.value); //Console.log = 2
},
```

Problem is that `category.value` is `2`? I would expect 2 json objects? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What you're doing by this `category.value = JSON.parse(category.value).push({meta: "", value: ""});` is simply assigning the return value of the `push` operation to `category.value` which before now doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
addSetting(category) {
 category.value = JSON.parse(category.value);
 category.value.push({meta: "", value: ""});
 console.log(category.value);
}
```

You are using `push()` incorrectly. The array function `push()` returns the size of the new array.

> Return value
>
> The new length property of the object upon which the method was
>   called.

ref:[Array.prototype.push() MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

As the new size of your array will be `2` (after pushing the new element) the following line was incorrect:

```
category.value = JSON.parse(category.value).push({meta: "", value: ""});
```

As after JSON was parsed, the variable category.value was assigned the return value of push.